# error in my cmd window regarding sfc/ scan now

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

When I try to run `SFC /SCAN NOW` in the command line window, it states "windows resource protection could not run/start the repair service". How can I fix this?

I tried running the system restore, with no success.

Is it possible that a keylogger is installed in my computer? How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 5):

Open the Services MMC Snapin (`services.msc`) and look for a service called `Windows Modules Installer` and make sure the service is started.

If you use a 64Bit Windows, make sure you run the 64Bit cmd.exe and not the 32Bit one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint about the 64bit cmd.exe.  I've been tearing my nonexistent hair out for over an hour over this.

Comment: How do you start the 64bit cmd.exe ?

Comment: @MatthewLock don't run the cmd from any 32Bit application (file manager). run it from the startmenu and it should be the 64Bit one.

Comment: If you are running 64 bit windows, but you keep getting the 32 bit command prompt, you can run "%WINDIR%\sysnative\cmd.exe" within the 32 bit cmd prompt to launch the 64 bit one.