# What is blocking sfc from running if there are no violations?

Tags: windows, sfc

I have a handful of Win7 Pro x64 machines with the same problem. Something is causing Windows to malfunction in different ways but it seems to be settings or parameters set up rather than corruption.

symptoms include: services refusing to stop, msiexec hangs when trying to uninstall programs, windows updates hangs when asked to do just about anything,  (windowsupdatediag.cab has no affect)

When attemping to run `sfc /scannow` from within the running Windows, I receive the error `Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.` (I also tried to start the trustedinstaller service but it said it was already running.)

However, when I run `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=x:\ /offwindir=x:\windows` from a Windows RE cd it tells me that there are no integrity violations.

I have also run `chkdsk /f /r x:` and received no reports of errors.

Could there be another windows program or service running that is tying up sfc? I have uninstalled and removed all non-microsoft software

Comment: You have not provided us the logs, that tell us the reason, please provide those.

Comment: If you are running, `sfc /scannow` from within WinRE, you are attempting to repair the WinRE not your Windows installation.

Comment: the full command I run in WinRE is `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=e:\ /offwindir=e:\windows` so it targets the OS drive

Comment: That isn't the command you said you used in your question.

Comment: [error in my cmd window regarding sfc/ scan now](http://superuser.com/questions/658154/error-in-my-cmd-window-regarding-sfc-scan-now)

Comment: "Something is causing Windows to not function properly " - be specific.

Comment: the trustedinstaller service is running and I am using the correct version of cmd. the problems consist of Windows services and applications hanging or being unresponsive when asked to perform a task.

Comment: DISM command is a great more helpful then SFC.  Have you tried that.  Without the log, again, I can't say why you are getting the resource protection error.